# I get an MYSQL error #1064 when add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, database, alter

I keep getting this sql error

```
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Option (OptionId)' at line 1"
```

when I try and add a foreign key to the OptionId field from the Question Table to the OptionId(pk) field in the Option field. I don't get wy I keep getting the error because I don't see what is wrong with it.

Below is the foreign key constraint using ALTER TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE Question ADD CONSTRAINT FK_OptionId FOREIGN KEY (OptionId) REFERENCES Option (OptionId)
```

Table names and syntax are correct, I made sure by double checking.

Why is it not working?

Comment: #1064 seems to be a generic mysql message where constraints are concerned.  i got it while trying to CREATE FOREIGN KEY on an existing table (rusty!).  your question reminded me that i had to ALTER TABLE.  so i voted you up.  thanx!

Answer (score 4):

`option` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL and must be surrounded by backticks.

```
ALTER TABLE Question
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_OptionId FOREIGN KEY (OptionId)
    REFERENCES `Option` (OptionId)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I didn't know option was already a reserve word, Thank You

Comment: the " ` " character also allows you to use a wider character set in naming variables and tables, including BLANK SPACE.  as a matter of style and procedure, i would rather not use it (" ` ") and have MySQL check name integrity for me (which becomes REALLY necessary if you are porting your DB to another DBengine).  kudos MichaelMior